# IIS 6 ASP encoding setting

Tags: iis-6, encoding, asp-classic

I migrated an ASP site from a Win2008R2 server running IIS 6.1 to a Win2012 server running IIS 6.1.  The IIS site settings did not migrate so easily.

One thing I just can't solve: When I send Arabic characters through ASP and into an MS SQL sproc from the old server they arrive as UTF-8.  When I do it on the new server – into *the same MS SQL 2008 server* – the Arabic arrives as a series of '?' with an occasional '_' either *during or after* being appended as a parameter to a Server "ADODB.Command" object.  (I can debug the code and see that the original Arabic representation is still in the variable that's handed to the sproc.)

If you know what setting is probably affecting this and where to find it that would be wonderful.

However, if you can at least tell me how I could export the complete *effective* IIS settings on each deployment so I can find the differences and apply them to the new instance that would be very helpful too!

Comment: Check/compare `system.web/globalization` in _IIS Manager_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP-encoding is largely tied up in the encoding of the source files themselves.  [There is no server setting that can overcome the functional effects of something as simple as a single ASP file being saved with a different encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38983861/2662901).